# Qt Horizontal pop-up menu/toolbar

Tags: c++, qt

What I want is something like horizontal pop-up context menu or toolbar.

Is there any way to do it without using QML?

Update: SSCCE explication:

So what I'm trying to do is some kind of QMenu/QToolBar. It should be context type with my QGraphicsItem and we can add sub menu into it. Graphically, it should be horizontal. 
[image]

Comment: QToolbar? you looked into that?

Comment: @AngryDuck Yes but how to pop up a context QToolBar?

Comment: `setWindowFlags( Qt::Popup );` + `show();` ?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Another question, plz. If I use Qtoolbar. I'll lose some Qmenu advantage, like adding a sub menu. Is there a way to customize smartly the look of Qmenu (which means that all QActions are automatically mapped to the look). Thanks.

Comment: You need to write mapping manually. For submenu analog you may use `QToolButton`

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Any hint on how to do this. I am newbee to Qt.

Comment: Please, describe exact problem (with SSCCE)... Another idea - create `QMenuBar` and set flag `Qt::Popup` to it. Try it.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov QMenuBar can add sub QMenu but not sub QMenuBar. What I need is a class can add an instance of itself as sub menu. Plz see the update.